# Reading a text file to a certain point and entering data at that point

Tags: c

Basically I'm programming in C, and what I'm trying to do is read a text file to a certain point, then once it's there then print my data calculated from the program.

I've read through all `fread`, `fseek`, `fgets` functions, etc.... but don't really understand how to use them. I have a .kml file which is to be used with google earth. My program calculates co-ordinates, so I want to put them in at a point of the file. Here is piece of data from the file:

```
/*******text file******/

Linestring

stlye

etc....

coordinates

3.0,36.8333333

1.986105,37.166788

0.963341,37.491533

-0.068231,37.807386

/*******eof*********/
```

So it should search until it reads coordinates then all my data should be entered.
I thought there maybe something like

```
char[25] = "coordinates";

if (function_that_searches_file == char){
    fprintf(myfile, "data%lf", data); // etc..
}
```

somewhere, but can't find anything. So any help or pointed to the right direction would much appreciated.

Comment: Find out how many characters you need to read before you reach the "coordinates" part. Then fseek to that point and insert your data. Think of your data as an array of char's you have to search through. Each newline is just a '\n' at some position in the array. You are on point with the fseek and your basic pseudocode. You're almost there :)

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't have Strings, so you can't compare them with an equality like that. You would have to use `strcmp()` to compare the two strings ([read about how to use it here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html)).

For example, you could create a loop that reads each line of the file, and in that loop put:

```
if(!strcmp(lineFromFile, "coordinates"))
{
    // Do something here
}
```

Note: `strcmp()` is a bit tricky to remember, because it returns a 0 when equal. That's why it's negated, because 0 is false in C.

Comment: Hey thanks for the replies.@MichaelThiessen But using strcmp, where will that leave me after finding the comparison?  I mean what do I need to add data at that point, once the comparison has been made.  As well, the first argument in the function you added, can that be a file pointer.